# Is there any way to infer how many workers are on the same node using MPI?

Tags: mpi

How can I tell how many workers are set up on the same node? I can get the overall `COMM_WORLD` size and even, using PMI, which rank a process is on the node. How can I tell how many processes are spun up on each node?

Comment: Use `MPI_Comm_split_type` to split the communicator into subcommunicators that live on a node. Then use `MPI_Comm_size` on those subcommunicators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Use `MPI_Comm_split_type` to find subcommunicators corresponding to nodes, then count how many there are, and their sizes.

```
  int main( int argc,char **argv ) {
  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
  int procno,nprocs;
  MPI_Comm_size( comm,&nprocs );
  MPI_Comm_rank( comm,&procno );

  MPI_Comm node_comm;
  MPI_Comm_split_type( comm,MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED,procno,MPI_INFO_NULL,&node_comm);
  int rank_on_node,size_of_node;
  MPI_Comm_rank( node_comm,&rank_on_node );
  MPI_Comm_size( node_comm,&size_of_node );
  int head_node = (rank_on_node==0);
  int number_of_nodes;
  MPI_Reduce( &head_node,&number_of_nodes,1,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0,comm);
  if (procno==0)
    printf("There are %d nodes\n",number_of_nodes);

  MPI_Comm node_heads;
  MPI_Comm_split( comm,head_node,procno,&node_heads );
  int node_sizes[number_of_nodes];
  MPI_Gather( &size_of_node,1,MPI_INT, node_sizes,1,MPI_INT, 0,node_heads );
  if (procno==0) {
    printf("Node sizes:");
    for (int inode=0; inode<number_of_nodes; inode++)
      printf(" %d",node_sizes[inode]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

For instance on my system if I request 3 nodes with 10 processes total, I get:

```
There are 3 nodes
Node sizes: 4 3 3
```

Nice. I'd sort of been expecting "4 4 2".

Comment: Very nifty. Would not have thought of that.